# OpenSSL critical CVE-2014-0195

Tags: security, https

Have anyone seen POC code for the new critical openssl bug CVE-2014-0195 ? (As seen on https://isc.sans.edu/) Do we need to worry about HTTPS here as well? Does not seem so....
Thanks,
Elder